# Recoding specific column values using reference list

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this

```
data = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
              Gender=c('Male','Female','Female','Female','Male','Female','Male','Male','Female','Female'))
```

And I have a reference list that looks like this -

```
ref=list(Male=1,Female=2)
```

I'd like to replace values in the `Gender` column using this reference list, without adding a new column to my dataframe.

Here's my attempt

```
do.call(dplyr::recode, c(list(data), ref))
```

Which gives me the following error -

> no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class
>   "data.frame"

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be do a `left_join` after `stack`ing the 'ref' `list` to a two column data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(data, stack(ref), by = c('Gender' = 'ind')) %>%
    select(ID, Gender = values)
```

---

A `base R` approach would be

```
unname(unlist(ref)[as.character(data$Gender)])
#[1] 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2
```

Comment: One note if list names are numeric, e.g., `list(0=1,1=2)`, the `stack` returns a factor as ind column. This may trigger errors as `dplyr` checks for a type of columns. So, an additional step like `stack$ind <- as.numeric(as.character(stack$ind))` may be needed where numeric outputs are required.

Comment: @gofraidh or may use `stack(ref) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

`data$Gender = sapply(data$Gender, function(x) ref[[x]])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `factor`, i.e.

```
factor(data$Gender, levels = names(ref), labels = ref)
#[1] 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `unlist` `ref` to give you a named vector of codes, and then index this with your data:

```
transform(data,Gender=unlist(ref)[as.character(Gender)])
   ID Gender
1   1      1
2   2      2
3   3      2
4   4      2
5   5      1
6   6      2
7   7      1
8   8      1
9   9      2
10 10      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, that one works as well:

```
data$Gender <- ref[as.character(data$Gender)]

#> data
#    ID Gender
# 1   1      1
# 2   2      2
# 3   3      2
# 4   4      2
# 5   5      1
# 6   6      2
# 7   7      1
# 8   8      1
# 9   9      2
# 10 10      2
```